# Automate Curl multiple HTTP requests

Tags: 16.04, server, bash, scripts, curl

On **Ubuntu server 16.04.6**, I am using **Curl** (**v. 7.47.0**) to test my web-server and network components.

Using the `-:` option (also known as `--next`), I keep the TCP connection open, and send multiple HTTP requests to my server, for example:

```
 curl -s -o /dev/null http://example.com/foo -: -s -d "data" http://example.com/bar -: http://example.com/foo
```

Now, assuming I would like to send exactly the same HTTP request 3 times, I would use:

```
curl -o /dev/null http://example.com/foo -: -o /dev/null http://example.com/foo -: -o /dev/null http://example.com/foo
```

**My question is:** is there a way to repeat this HTTP request to the same uri with same options "n" amount of times without adding `-: -o /dev/null http://example.com/foo` over and over again?

For example, sending 100 of the same HTTP requests using the same TCP connection without writing `-: -o /dev/null http://example.com/foo` 99 times?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `xargs` for this purpose like this:

```
for i in {1..100} ; do
  echo ' -o /dev/null http://example.com/foo -:'
done | xargs curl -s
```

Please, note that `xargs` will **not** produce a command larger than 2,088,616 characters in *my* system. You can determine this maximum length in *your* system by running `xargs --show-limits` in your system.

Comment: Ohh `xargs` is a great solution (I'm just not that familiar with using `xargs`). Alternatively,  I built my command in a single line as follows: `for i in {1..100}; do echo ' -o /dev/null http://example.com/foo -:'; done | xargs curl -s`.  A follow up question though: how does piping `xargs` works if `echo` command is being executed and writes to the output stream inside the `for` loop, while `| xargs` is outside the loop?

Comment: I put it deliberately outside the `for` loop, so that *all* the output produced by 100 `echo`s is concatenated as a single input the `xargs`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer - this will be a great addition for my script. I do have a problem with the last `-:` generated by `xargs`, resulting an additional `Curl` with a missing url error, but I'll be able to handle with no problems.